# How to create a Pandas crosstab with a custom aggregate function with mixture of two variables?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have 4 variables `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, I want the crosstab to look like this:

```
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  A/B  |      Cat1       |      Cat2       |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Cat-a | Sum(C)/Count(D) | Sum(C)/Count(D) |
| Cat-b | Sum(C)/Count(D) | Sum(C)/Count(D) |
+-------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Eg. My data looks like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Type | Gender | Height | Weight |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Dog  | F      |     80 |     60 |
| Dog  | F      |     75 |     57 |
| Dog  | M      |     90 |     68 |
| Cat  | F      |     50 |     50 |
| Cat  | F      |     53 |     53 |
| Cat  | M      |     56 |     55 |
| Cat  | M      |     60 |     54 |
| Cat  | M      |     65 |     60 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now suppose I want the aggregate to be sum(weight)/max(height). The crosstab would look something like:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| Type/Gender |     M      |     F      |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| Cat         | 169/65=2.6 | 103/53=1.9 |
| Dog         | 68/90=0.75 | 117/80=1.4 |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Answer (score 2):

First aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `max` and `sum`, then create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with division, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and last data cleaning - [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Type','Gender'])
         .agg({'Height':'max','Weight':'sum'})
         .assign(New = lambda x: x.Weight / x.Height)['New']
         .unstack()
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

print (df1)
  Type         F         M
0  Cat  1.943396  2.600000
1  Dog  1.462500  0.755556
```